# Spawning tasks with non-static lifetimes with tokio 0.1.x

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-tokio

I have a tokio core whose main task is running a websocket (client). When I receive some messages from the server, I want to execute a new task that will update some data. Below is a minimal failing example:

```
use tokio_core::reactor::{Core, Handle};
use futures::future::Future;
use futures::future;

struct Client {
    handle: Handle,
    data: usize,
}

impl Client {
    fn update_data(&mut self) {
        // spawn a new task that updates the data
        self.handle.spawn(future::ok(()).and_then(|x| {
            self.data += 1; // error here
            future::ok(())
        }));
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut runtime = Core::new().unwrap();

    let mut client = Client {
        handle: runtime.handle(),
        data: 0,
    };

    let task = future::ok::<(), ()>(()).and_then(|_| {
        // under some conditions (omitted), we update the data
        client.update_data();
        future::ok::<(), ()>(())
    });
    runtime.run(task).unwrap();
}
```

Which produces this error:

```
error[E0477]: the type `futures::future::and_then::AndThen<futures::future::result_::FutureResult<(), ()>, futures::future::result_::FutureResult<(), ()>, [closure@src/main.rs:13:51: 16:10 self:&mut &mut Client]>` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:13:21                                                                                                                                                                
   |                                                                                                                                                                                   
13 |         self.handle.spawn(future::ok(()).and_then(|x| {                                                                                                                           
   |                     ^^^^^                                                                                                                                                         
   |                                                                                                                                                                                   
   = note: type must satisfy the static lifetime
```

The problem is that new tasks that are spawned through a handle need to be static. The same issue is described [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/ownership-issues-with-tokio-and-multiple-types-of-futures/10718). Sadly it is unclear to me how I can fix the issue. Even some attempts with and `Arc` and a `Mutex` (which really shouldn't be needed for a single-threaded application), I was unsuccessful.

Since developments occur rather quickly in the tokio landscape, I am wondering what the current best solution is. Do you have any suggestions?

### **edit**

The solution by [Peter Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/493729/peter-hall) works for the example above. Sadly when I built the failing example I changed tokio reactor, thinking they would be similar. Using `tokio::runtime::current_thread`

```
use futures::future;
use futures::future::Future;
use futures::stream::Stream;
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::rc::Rc;
use tokio::runtime::current_thread::{Builder, Handle};

struct Client {
    handle: Handle,
    data: Rc<Cell<usize>>,
}

impl Client {
    fn update_data(&mut self) {
        // spawn a new task that updates the data
        let mut data = Rc::clone(&self.data);
        self.handle.spawn(future::ok(()).and_then(move |_x| {
            data.set(data.get() + 1);
            future::ok(())
        }));
    }
}

fn main() {
    // let mut runtime = Core::new().unwrap();

    let mut runtime = Builder::new().build().unwrap();

    let mut client = Client {
        handle: runtime.handle(),
        data: Rc::new(Cell::new(1)),
    };

    let task = future::ok::<(), ()>(()).and_then(|_| {
        // under some conditions (omitted), we update the data
        client.update_data();
        future::ok::<(), ()>(())
    });
    runtime.block_on(task).unwrap();
}
```

I obtain:

```
error[E0277]: `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::Cell<usize>>` cannot be sent between threads safely
--> src/main.rs:17:21                                                         
|                                                                            
17 |         self.handle.spawn(future::ok(()).and_then(move |_x| {              
|                     ^^^^^ `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::Cell<usize>>` cannot be sent between threads safely
|                                                                            
= help: within `futures::future::and_then::AndThen<futures::future::result_::FutureResult<(), ()>, futures::future::result_::FutureResult<(), ()>, [closure@src/main.rs:17:51: 20:10 data:std::rc::Rc<std::cell::Cell<usize>>]>`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `std::rc::Rc<std::cell::Cell<usize>>`
= note: required because it appears within the type `[closure@src/main.rs:17:51: 20:10 data:std::rc::Rc<std::cell::Cell<usize>>]`
= note: required because it appears within the type `futures::future::chain::Chain<futures::future::result_::FutureResult<(), ()>, futures::future::result_::FutureResult<(), ()>, [closure@src/main.rs:17:51: 20:10 data:std::rc::Rc<std::cell::Cell<usize>>]>`
= note: required because it appears within the type `futures::future::and_then::AndThen<futures::future::result_::FutureResult<(), ()>, futures::future::result_::FutureResult<(), ()>, [closure@src/main.rs:17:51: 20:10 data:std::rc::Rc<std::cell::Cell<usize>>]>`
```

So it does seem like in this case I need an `Arc` and a `Mutex` even though the entire code is single-threaded?

Comment: Please do not [update your already-answered question to ask new questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253762/link-for-poor-or-ever-growing-questions-to-better-explain-why-people-stop-answer). Instead, take the time to create an improved [MCVE], ask a new question, explain how the two questions differ, and potentially link between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a single-threaded program, you don't need to use `Arc`; `Rc` is sufficient:

```
use std::{rc::Rc, cell::Cell};

struct Client {
    handle: Handle,
    data: Rc<Cell<usize>>,
}

impl Client {
    fn update_data(&mut self) {
        let data = Rc::clone(&self.data);
        self.handle.spawn(future::ok(()).and_then(move |_x| {
            data.set(data.get() + 1);
            future::ok(())
        }));
    }
}
```

The point is that you no longer have to worry about the lifetime because each clone of the `Rc` acts as if it owns the data, rather than accessing it via a reference to `self`. The inner `Cell` (or `RefCell` for non-`Copy` types) is needed because the `Rc` can't be dereferenced mutably, since it has been cloned.

---

The `spawn` method of `tokio::runtime::current_thread::Handle` requires that the future is `Send`, which is what is causing the problem in the update to your question. There is an explanation (of sorts) for why this is the case in [this Tokio Github issue](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/issues/744).

You can use `tokio::runtime::current_thread::spawn` instead of the method of `Handle`, which will always run the future in the current thread, and does *not* require that the future is `Send`. You can replace `self.handle.spawn` in the code above and it will work just fine.

If you need to use the method on `Handle` then you will also need to resort to `Arc` and `Mutex` (or [`RwLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.RwLock.html)) in order to satisfy the `Send` requirement:

```
use std::sync::{Mutex, Arc};

struct Client {
    handle: Handle,
    data: Arc<Mutex<usize>>,
}

impl Client {
    fn update_data(&mut self) {
        let data = Arc::clone(&self.data);
        self.handle.spawn(future::ok(()).and_then(move |_x| {
            *data.lock().unwrap() += 1;
            future::ok(())
        }));
    }
}
```

If your data is really a `usize`, you could also use `AtomicUsize` instead of `Mutex<usize>`, but I personally find it just as unwieldy to work with.